# Using Homebrew python3 with both homebrew packages and pip/pip3 packages in Visual Studio Code for Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, homebrew

I am currently trying to setup Visual Studio Code on Mac OSX 10.13.6 for coding in `python3`. I'd like to avoid using multiple virtual environments for my different `python3` scripts and instead have them all run using:

(1) the same `homebrew` installation of `python3`

(2) accessing installed python packages in:

- `homebrew` packages list
- `pip3` installed package list
- `pip` installed packages list.

First, I first installed `python3` using `homebrew`:

```
$ brew info python
python: stable 3.7.7 (bottled), HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7 (4,062 files, 62.4MB)
...
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3
...
You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Second, I installed my required packages using `homebrew`:

```
$ brew list
cmake           libffi          p11-kit
dcraw           libheif         pandoc
dlib            libidn2         pcre
...
jasper          numpy           webp
...
```

And other packages using `pip` and `pip3`:

```
$ pip list
DEPRECATION:...
Package                                Version 
-------------------------------------- --------
altgraph                               0.10.2  
...
numpy                                  1.8.0rc1
...
zope.interface                         4.1.1  
$
$ pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
appnope            0.1.0  
... 
numpy              1.18.2 
pandocfilters      1.4.2  
parso              0.5.2  
pexpect            4.7.0  
pickleshare        0.7.5  
pip                20.0.2 
pomegranate        0.12.2 
...
scipy              1.4.1
```

Third, I opened Visual Studio Code and in "Preferences" -> "Settings" and set `"Python:Python Path"` to the `homebrew` `python3` installation as noted above `/usr/local/bin/python3`.

See this screenshot:
[image: Python:Python Path]

Next, I added `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` per the `homebrew` install of `python3` to the Visual Studio Code Settings file using:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages" ]
```

Finally, I selected my python interpreter in Visual Studio Code as `/usr/local/bin/python3` and tried to run the following 2-lines of imports in a `.py` script as per the screenshot below. Note that the interpreter is `Python 3.7.0 64-bit` given by the bottom left corner of the VS Code window.

[image: VS Code Screenshot]

And after all of that, ended up with this output after clicking the "Play" button to run the code in the top right corner of VS Code:

```
[Running] python -u "/Users/...bayes_net_nodes.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/...bayes_net_nodes.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.037 seconds
```

What would be the most simple way to configure VS Code so I can run `python3` scripts that have access to the all the packages I've installed across my system without using virtual environments?  Thank you!

Note: One workaround that seems to work, and I'm not sure why is if I put a shebang at the top of my script `#! /usr/local/bin/python3` and my output then looks like this:

```
[Running]  /usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/...bayes_net_nodes.py"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.051 seconds
```

Which is odd, because that's different than the output above where I didn't use the shebang but both python interpreters according to VSCode are indeed `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: When you do `/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip list`, do you see `numpy`? (Yes I know you listed your `pip3` list, but I just want to confirm that Homebrew's `python3` is where that numpy is really installed.)

Comment: Confirmed, definitely listed.

Comment: From your console logs, are you using [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)? Do you have it installed?

Comment: The coderunner part was from running without saving. Updated the console logs to show what happens when trying to run a saved program. Same error except no coderunner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem.. but **only when I use Code Runner** to run.

[image]

Those kind of Output logs with `[Running]` and `[Done]` *is* Code Runner.
The play button is also not green, indicating Code Runner because the default is green.

Now, for the fix!

You'll notice that it executed your script using `python -u`. That `python` would be whatever `python` means on your system, which for me is the default Python 2.7. Basically, it's not your Homebrew Python3 with numpy.

Code Runner has a default set of "executors" which tells it which executable to use for which language. Search it for in your settings as "code-runner Executor Map":

[image]

Open your *settings.json*, enter `code-runner.executorMap`, then let it auto-complete with the default. You'll then see a long list of mappings between language and executor. Look for the one for `python`:

```
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "javascript": "node",
        ...
        "python": "python -u",
        "perl": "perl",
        ...
    }
```

And there it is: `python -u`, the same one it used to run your script.

If you want to continue using Code Runner, simply change it to the whichever `python` interpreter you want to use. In your case, it should be `/usr/local/bin/python3`:

```
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        ...
        "python": "/usr/local/bin/python3",
        ...
    }
```

It should now work:

[image]

The reason it works with a `#! /usr/local/bin/python3` shebang is because Code Runner has a setting that it respects the file's shebang (`code-runner.respectShebang`) which is true by default.

If you don't want this extra step of setting-up Code Runner, you can simply disable (or uninstall it). All the steps you already did (setting `python.pythonPath`, selecting the interpreter, and clicking that Play button) would have already worked just fine with Microsoft's [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python). See the official docs on [running Python files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_run-hello-world), [selecting environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments), and [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).